# cURL login and redirect [It's an ASP.net page]

Tags: php, redirect, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login at www.z8games.com and go to the settings page, this is the code I'm using and the error is below.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.z8games.com/loging/globelogin.aspx?b=4&from=';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('~<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\" />~',$html,$viewstate);
    preg_match('~<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\" />~',$html,$eventvalidation);
    $vstate = $viewstate[1];
    $eval = $eventvalidation[1];
    $post_fields='__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=' . urlencode($vstate) . '&__EVENTVALIDATION=' . urlencode($eval) . '&tb_loginid=Heroboss123&tb_password=Droppers1&ib_login.x=11&ib_login.y=19';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7s");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Changing from page
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.z8games.com/myaccount/myaccount.aspx");
    $store = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $store;

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

It returns this:

[image: error page]

Comment: So, have you tried to enable "debug mode" as suggested?  Do you even have access to the aspx page?  Is `z8games` even your site?

Comment: its a breach of z8games Terms of Use, so maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: I don't see anything about logging into their site.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting login credential to the wrong URL.

Remove this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.z8games.com/myaccount/myaccount.aspx");
```

And use this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

**UPDATE:**

to get the content from another page, change the url, and also use the HTTP request as GET. Currently you are doing it as POST. So it should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.z8games.com/myaccount/myaccount.aspx");
```

Comment: I want to login and change the page, login does work, but changing from page doens't work.

Comment: Ok, but it just keeps loading and at the end it returns a white page.